# How to run kubernetes on a virtual windows server 2019?

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, minikube

I am trying to run an Orleans silo using Kubernetes deployed on a Windows Server 2019. I am using HyperV for the virtual machine and minikube to run kubectl. I have been trying to follow tutorials on how to use Kubernetes like this one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1IEPuYSkGU, but for some reason it doesn't work when I get to starting minikube. A virtual machine is made but I cannot log into it. I have tried using the default login "docker" "tcuser". Kubectl also responds weird saying the connection was actively refused.

Here is the result of kubectl get po -A:

E0326 12:18:24.543097    1900 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
E0326 12:18:24.544614    1900 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
E0326 12:18:24.546419    1900 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
E0326 12:18:24.547465    1900 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
E0326 12:18:24.548531    1900 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Here is the result of minikube start:

- minikube v1.32.0 on Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard Evaluation 10.0.17763.5576 Build 17763.5576
- Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration
  ! --network flag is only valid with the docker/podman, KVM and Qemu drivers, it will be ignored
- Downloading VM boot image ...

  > minikube-v1.32.1-amd64.iso....:  65 B / 65 B [---------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
  > minikube-v1.32.1-amd64.iso:  292.96 MiB / 292.96 MiB  100.00% 9.35 MiB p/
- Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
- Downloading Kubernetes v1.28.3 preload ...

  > preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  403.35 MiB / 403.35 MiB  100.00% 8.49 Mi
- Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
- Stopping node "minikube"  ...
- Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...
- Deleting "minikube" in hyperv ...
  ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
  E0326 12:02:37.854034    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
  At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

E0326 12:02:39.239129    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

E0326 12:02:40.620153    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

- Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...E0326 12:02:42.019016    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
  At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

E0326 12:02:43.408844    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

E0326 12:02:44.795062    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

E0326 12:02:46.178967    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

E0326 12:02:47.559842    5268 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3

- ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
- ```
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
  ```

- Failed to start hyperv VM. Running "minikube delete" may fix it: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

X Exiting due to DRV_CREATE_TIMEOUT: Failed to start host: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds

- Suggestion: Try 'minikube delete', and disable any conflicting VPN or firewall software
- Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7072

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.